# No documentation for Ehcache 2.4.3

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I am running hibernate 4.1.2.Final version of hibernate and i have found ehcache-core version of 2.4.3 in its optional folder. When i went to search for documentation for that version of ehcache i could not find it on the  [website.](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/#historical_versions)

I really wonder! I wanted to set up the parameters to set up both. How can i set up both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to follow the documentation for 4.3.1 and it worked. The two properties I used are

```
 <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```

and it works!